# Restarting Rowcolors

Tags: tables

This should be a simple question. I am using `\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}` to alternate coloring of rows in a table.

Is there a way to "restart" the re-coloring after a certain point so that I ensure that regardless of how many rows are above, I can guarantee that the alternating behavior resumes starting with a given, pre-set row?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}             % tables with footnotes, capions all the same width
\usepackage{dcolumn}                    % decimal-aligned tabular math columns
\usepackage{multirow}                   % Allow table cells to span multiple rows
\usepackage{booktabs}                   % Formatting options for publication-quality tables
\usepackage{ltxtable}                   % long tabularx
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
\begin{document}
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\LTXtable{\textwidth}{testtable}
\end{document}
```

testtable.tex:

```
\begin{longtable}{p{3cm} X}
    \toprule
    Heading row & This should be lightgrey \\
    \hline % I use \hline because \midrule counts as a row and screws with the colors
    A data row & This row should be uncolored \\
    A data row & This row should be lightgrey \\
    A data row & This row sometimes doesn't exist. It would be uncolored if it did \\
    \hline
    A new heading row & This should be lightgrey regardless of whether the previous row exists.
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: You can place `\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}` inside the table, just before the point in which the coloring should "restart".

Comment: @GonzaloMedina That's not compiling, unfortunately.

Comment: sure it is in the following case: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{cc}
textc1 & textc2 \\
textc1 & textc2 \\
textc1 & textc2 \\
textc1 & textc2 \\
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
textc1 & textc2 \\
textc1 & textc2 \\
textc1 & textc2 \\
textc1 & textc2 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}` See how important a MWE can be?

Comment: I should say "it's not working". It's 6 PM. Brain also not working.

Comment: I suppose it could be something with the `ltxtable` package. Your MWE works. That intervention in my own does not.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Package `xcolor` remembers the state of the colored row via count register `\rownum`. This can be reset to the initial value via:

```
\global\rownum=0\relax
```

It is too late to change the count register in the current row. Thus it needs to be done in a cell of the previous row.

The following example adds a LaTeX interface for `\rownum` to get macros `\setcounter`, `\addtocounter`, and `\therownum` working. Then the counter is reset in the row right before the lines, marked with `restart`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}

% LaTeX counter interface for \rownum
% ---
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{c@rownum}{%
  \let\c@rownum\rownum
}{}
\@ifundefined{therownum}{%
  \def\therownum{\@arabic\rownum}%
}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\rowcolors{1}{yellow}{red}
\begin{tabular}{>{\the\rownum}ll}
\hline
&\\
&\\
&\\
&\setcounter{rownum}{0}\\
\hline
\hline
& restart\\
&\\
&\setcounter{rownum}{0}\\
\hline
\hline
& restart\\
&\setcounter{rownum}{0}\\
\hline
\hline
& restart\\
&\\
&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remark:**

- `\rowcolors{1}{yellow}{red}` means, start with the first row with the altering row colors. the first color is used for odd numbered rows, the second color for even numbered rows.

### Package `longtable`

Much more "fun" is package `longtable`. It takes `LTchunksize` rows for measuring the table cell widths. Therefore a row can be processed *several* times. This affect `\rownum`. The previous example with `\usepackage{longtable}` and `longtable` instead of `tabular`:

> [image: Result]

Or with `\setcounter{LTchunksize}{1}` (and several LaTeX runs):

> [image: Result LTchunksize=1]

---

Already `longtable` causes trouble with the row numbering, therefore it will not become better with `ltxtable`, because it is based on `longtable`.
In the example below, the first row gets number 2, thus the first argument of `\rowcolors` will not work reliable unless it is set to 1.

To some degree the "resetting" is working, if it is done in the previous row.
However the first row should be white not lightgray according to `\rowcolors`
and the row numbering is not working correctly.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{testtable1.tex}
\begin{longtable}{>{\the\rownum.}r p{3.5cm} X}
    \toprule
    & Heading row & This should be lightgrey \\
    \hline
    & A data row & This row should be uncolored \\
    & A data row & This row should be lightgrey \\
    & A data row & This row sometimes doesn't exist.
                   It would be uncolored if it did
    \restartrowcolors\\
    \midrule
    & A new heading row & This should be lightgrey regardless
      of whether the previous row exists.\\
    & A data row & This should be uncolored \\
    & A data row & This should be lightgrey
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testtable2.tex}
\begin{longtable}{>{\the\rownum.}r p{3.5cm} X >{\the\rownum}l}
    \toprule
    & Heading row & This should be lightgrey \\
    \hline
    & A data row & This row should be uncolored \\
    & A data row & This row should be lightgrey 
    \restartrowcolors\\
    \midrule
    & A new heading row & This should be lightgrey regardless
      of whether the previous row exists.\\
    & A data row & This should be uncolored \\
    & A data row & This should be lightgrey
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}                   % Formatting options for publication-quality tables
\usepackage{ltxtable}                   % long tabularx
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}

\newcommand*{\restartrowcolors}{%
  \ifhmode\unskip\fi
  \vadjust{%
    \global\rownum=0 %
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\LTXtable{\textwidth}{testtable1}
\LTXtable{\textwidth}{testtable2}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I can get this working, but not when I convert the hlines to midrules.

Comment: Ah, I got it to work! I simply used `%A data row & This row sometimes doesn't exist.  It would be uncolored if it did\\
 \noalign{\global\rownum=1}%
    \midrule` instead of `hline`

Comment: @Arkamis: The problem is not `\hline` vs. `\midrule`, but the row numbering, if package `longtable` is involved. I have updated and fixed the answer.

Comment: Is it possible to automate the call of `\setcounter{rownum}{0}` at the last cell of a table? I'm using the `tabu` package. By having this, one does not have to remember to always put that code in the last cell.

Comment: @Sam There is no automatism, because it depends on the user, in which rows he wants to place `\setcounter{rownum}{0}`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Yeah, it depends on the user, but if you have a `table` environment with two subtables – in my case `tabu` environments – the second table quite often starts with a different colour. I would like to add the reset code to the end of the `tabu` environment, so I can make sure, that every table starts with the same colour, even if I forget to manually add the code. If for any reason, I need to reset the table like in the original question, I could still manually add the code wherever I want.

Comment: @Sam Ask a new question. Then, you can provide a proper example and the `tabu` experts can answer.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek That was the plan for the case that nobody can provide a very simple solution in this thread. ;)

Comment: There is a very simple solution I just found in the [documentation of the tabu environment](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tabu/tabu.pdf). `tabu` provides a `\taburowcolors` command which does restart at each occurrence. It's on page 18 in the current docs as of today.

Answer (score 6):

You cam simply say `rowcolor{lightgray}` just before the row that you want to be colored regardless of your row color definition earlier.

If previous row doesn't exist:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}             % tables with footnotes, capions all the same width
\usepackage{dcolumn}                    % decimal-aligned tabular math columns
\usepackage{multirow}                   % Allow table cells to span multiple rows
\usepackage{booktabs}                   % Formatting options for publication-quality tables
\usepackage{ltxtable}                   % long tabularx
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{testtable.tex}
    \rowcolors{1}{white}{lightgray}
  \begin{longtable}{p{3cm} X}
    \toprule
    Heading row & This should be lightgrey \\
    \hline % I use \hline because \midrule counts as a row and screws with the colors
    A data row & This row should be uncolored \\
    A data row & This row should be lightgrey \\
%    A data row & This row sometimes doesn't exist. It would be uncolored if it did \\
%    \hline
    \rowcolor{lightgray}
        \rowcolors{5}{white}{lightgray}
    A new heading row & This should be lightgrey regardless of whether the previous row exists.\\
    A data row & This row should be uncolored \\
    A data row & This row should be lightgrey \\
    A data row & This row sometimes doesn't exist. It would be uncolored if it did \\
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\LTXtable{\textwidth}{testtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here from fourth row colors are alternate.

If previous row exists:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}             % tables with footnotes, capions all the same width
\usepackage{dcolumn}                    % decimal-aligned tabular math columns
\usepackage{multirow}                   % Allow table cells to span multiple rows
\usepackage{booktabs}                   % Formatting options for publication-quality tables
\usepackage{ltxtable}                   % long tabularx
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{testtable.tex}
    \rowcolors{1}{white}{lightgray}
  \begin{longtable}{p{3cm} X}
    \toprule
    Heading row & This should be lightgrey \\
    \hline % I use \hline because \midrule counts as a row and screws with the colors
    A data row & This row should be uncolored \\
    A data row & This row should be lightgrey \\
    A data row & This row sometimes doesn't exist. It would be uncolored if it did \\
    \hline
    %\rowcolor{lightgray}
    %\rowcolors{4}{white}{lightgray}     
    A new heading row & This should be lightgrey regardless of whether the previous row exists.\\
    A data row & This row should be uncolored \\
    A data row & This row should be lightgrey \\
    A data row & This row sometimes doesn't exist. It would be uncolored if it did \\
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\LTXtable{\textwidth}{testtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This turns the heading row gray, but it doesn't set the row under it to white. It doesn't "restart" the alternating.

Comment: @Arkamis See the update. Is it OK?

Comment: Harish, I will test when I get into the office. It looks like either this solution or the other will work. We shall see!

Comment: @Arkamis You can rely on Heiko's macros and remedies always :). It was a good decision to use his trick. Have a nice time. :)