# Alternating rowcoloring by xcolor not identical for all tables

Tags: tables, scrbook, rowcolor

I am trying to apply alternating colors to my document, by use of the xcolor package with the table option. As far as I am aware it is possible to define the alternating colors in the preamble, so they are applied to all following tables.

But if I use it this way I dont get identical tablecolouring. Where am I wrong with this approach?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\rowcolors{2}{gray}{white}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|ll|}
            \hline
            $1_1$ & $1_2$ \\
            \hline
            $2_1$ & $2_2$ \\
            \hline
            $3_1$ & $3_2$ \\
            \hline
            $4_1$ & $4_2$ \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    Text

    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|ll|}
            \hline
            $1_1$ & $1_2$ \\
            \hline
            $2_1$ & $2_2$ \\
            \hline
            $3_1$ & $3_2$ \\
            \hline
            $4_1$ & $4_2$ \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\global\rownum=0\relax` between the tables ... See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170637/restarting-rowcolors

Comment: If you repeat `\rowcolors` before each table, there's no problem.

Comment: @koleygr Thanks, I did not find that question when searching this issue

Comment: Welcome @LaKi ... I just found that because I was sure there is a counter used in there ... So, just searched with the word counter in my "sentence"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\rowcolors{2}{gray}{white}

\let\oldtabular\tabular
\def\tabular{\global\rownum=0\relax\oldtabular}


\begin{document}    
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|ll|}
        \hline
        $1_1$ & $1_2$ \\
        \hline
        $2_1$ & $2_2$ \\
        \hline
        $3_1$ & $3_2$ \\
        \hline
        $4_1$ & $4_2$ \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

Text



\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|ll|}
        \hline
        $1_1$ & $1_2$ \\
        \hline
        $2_1$ & $2_2$ \\
        \hline
        $3_1$ & $3_2$ \\
        \hline
        $4_1$ & $4_2$ \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```